# How do I set a fallback entry by id or title in GRUB?

Tags: debian, boot, grub2

How do I set the fallback entry by ID or select an entry in a submenu? The only option that works currently is using numbered entries (i.e. `set fallback=0`).

**Background**

My team remotely updates devices running Debian. These units are deployed remotely, so physical or KVM access is infrequent and therefore not a viable solution. We copy the new system image onto an identical partition (/dev/sda2 in this case).

```
root@widget:~# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    1 186.3G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    1   953M  0 part /boot
├─sda2   8:2    1  23.3G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    1  23.3G  0 part /alt
```

After remounting the `/alt` partition, we want to verify that the image is not corrupt. To test this, we make a custom entry (e.g. `newimg` in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`).
The UUID starting with `xxxxxxxx` is the partition mounted on `/boot` (`dev/sda1`) and the UUID starting with `yyyyyyyy` is the partition mounted on `/` (`/dev/sda3`).

```
menuentry 'Debian 10 (buster) newimg' --id newimg {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
        linux /vmlinuz-4.2 root=UUID=yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy ro nomodeset panic=5 quiet
        initrd /initrd.img-4.2
}
set fallback='1>2'
```

Next we run `update-grub` and `grub-reboot newimg` to perform a one time reboot. In the case that the image is corrupt, we need a fallback image so we don't lose access to the terminal. In the past we would use the first grub menu entry as the fallback (`set fallback=0`). However, the new `/vmlinuz-4.2` will be used in the newest or `0` entry, so that would pointlessly fall back to itself. I have been testing fallback with the corrupt image `vmlinuz-4.2`. According to the [GRUB documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#default),

> The entry may be identified by number (starting from 0 at each level of the hierarchy), by title, or by id.

However, the only valid method I've seen is using the numbers (I can't get submenu entries to work either). With every other option I get this error message: `Failed to boot both default and fallback entries`.

**Things I've tried:**

- If I change the fallback in `40_custom` to `set fallback='1>2'` (`Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux > Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.1`) it does select entry `1`, but it does `1>0` instead of `1>2`. And `1>0` selects the same corrupted vmlinuz image.
- I also tried adding another custom boot entry that uses the old kernel (`defaultimg`) and changing the fallback to `set fallback=defaultimg` after verifying that I can successfully boot manually to `defaultimg`.
- I tried changing both of the previous options without the `set` and with single quotes and double quotes.

GRUB version: `2.02+dfsg1-20`

Comment: `it does select entry 1, but it does 1>0 instead of 1>2` : same behavior in Debian 11, it seems alway to fall back to entry 0, even thought I never configured entry 0 as a fallback.

Comment: I don't understand the problem here. There are two root partitions, `sda2` and `sda3`. So creating two menu entries, one for each root, and setting `default=0 fallback=1` or vice-versa should be sufficient.

I also don't see why there is a `search --set-root xxxx` being used. `xxxx` is said to be the UUID of the boot partition. The boot partition is usually not the root, and we should not be trying to set it as the root.